# How to display sum of value in stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a stacked bar chart, which has labels in the every stack. And each label has 2 rows in the data. I am able to display the first occurrence of value on the chart, but the chart should be display sum of those 2 values.

Below is my code:

```
 var outerWidth = 960;
  var outerHeight = 500;
  var margin = { left: 130, top: 44, right: 30, bottom: 47 };
  var barPadding = 0.2;

  var xColumn = "country";
  var yColumn = "population";
  var colorColumn = "religion";
  var layerColumn = colorColumn;

  var hoveredColorValue;
  var hoveredStrokeColor = "black";

  var innerWidth  = outerWidth  - margin.left - margin.right;
  var innerHeight = outerHeight - margin.top  - margin.bottom;

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",  outerWidth)
    .attr("height", outerHeight);
  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // This is the layer where the bars are drawn.
  var baseBarLayer = g.append("g");

  // This layer contains a semi-transparent overlay
  // that fades out the base bars.
  var overlayRect = g.append("g")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", innerWidth)
    .attr("height", innerHeight)
    .style("pointer-events", "none");

  // This contains the subset of bars rendered on top
  // when you hover over the entries in the color legend.
  var foregroundBarLayer = g.append("g");

  var xAxisG = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerHeight + ")");
  var yAxisG = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis");
  var colorLegendG = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "color-legend")
    .attr("transform", "translate(596, 0)");

  var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, innerWidth], barPadding);
  var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([innerHeight, 0]);
  var colorScale = d3.scale.category10();

  var tipNumberFormat = d3.format(",");
  var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr("class", "d3-tip")
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function(d) {
      return [
        d[colorColumn],
        " in ",
        d[xColumn],
        ": ",
        tipNumberFormat(d[yColumn])
      ].join("");
    });
  g.call(tip);

  // Use a modified SI formatter that uses "B" for Billion.
  var siFormat = d3.format("s");
  var customTickFormat = function (d){
    return siFormat(d).replace("G", "B");
  };

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom")
    .outerTickSize(0);
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left")
    .ticks(5)
    .tickFormat(customTickFormat)
    .outerTickSize(0);

  var colorLegend = d3.legend.color()
    .scale(colorScale)
    .shapePadding(6.24)
    .shapeWidth(25)
    .shapeHeight(25)
    .labelOffset(5);

  function render(data){

    var nested = d3.nest()
      .key(function (d){ return d[layerColumn]; })
      .entries(data);

    var stack = d3.layout.stack()
      .y(function (d){ return d[yColumn]; })
      .values(function (d){ return d.values; });

    var layers = stack(nested.reverse()).reverse();

    xScale.domain(layers[0].values.map(function (d){
      return d[xColumn];
    }));

    yScale.domain([
      0,
      d3.max(layers, function (layer){
        return d3.max(layer.values, function (d){
          return d.y0 + d.y;
        });
      })
    ]);

    colorScale.domain(layers.map(function (layer){
      return layer.key;
    }));

    xAxisG.call(xAxis); 
    yAxisG.call(yAxis);

    renderBars(baseBarLayer, layers);

    if(hoveredColorValue){
      setOverlayTransparency(0.7);
      renderBars(foregroundBarLayer, layers.filter(function (layer){
        return layer.key === hoveredColorValue;
      }));
    } else {
      setOverlayTransparency(0.0);
      renderBars(foregroundBarLayer, []);
    }

    colorLegendG.call(colorLegend);

    // Move the text down a bit.
    colorLegendG.selectAll("text").attr("y", 4);

    listenForHover(colorLegendG.selectAll("rect"), data);
    listenForHover(colorLegendG.selectAll("text"), data);
  }

  function setOverlayTransparency(alpha){
    overlayRect
      .transition().duration(400)
      .attr("fill", "rgba(255, 255, 255, " + alpha + ")");
  }

  function renderBars(g, layers){
    var layerGs = g.selectAll(".layer").data(layers);
    layerGs.enter().append("g").attr("class", "layer");
    layerGs.exit().remove();
    layerGs.style("fill", function (d){
      return colorScale(d.key);
    });

    var bars = layerGs.selectAll("rect").data(function (d){
      return d.values;
    });
    bars.enter().append("rect")
      .on("mouseover", tip.show)
      .on("mouseout", tip.hide);
    bars.exit().remove();
    bars
      .attr("x", function (d){ return xScale(d[xColumn]); })
      .attr("y", function (d){ return yScale(d.y0 + d.y); })
      .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
      .attr("height", function (d){ return innerHeight - yScale(d.y); });
  }

  function listenForHover(selection, data){
    selection
      .on("mouseover", function (d){
        hoveredColorValue = d;
        render(data);
      })
      .on("mouseout", function (d){
        hoveredColorValue = null;
        render(data);
      })
      .style("cursor", "pointer");
  }

  function type(d){
    d.population = +d.population;
    return d;
  }

  d3.csv("data.csv", type, render);
```

and below is the sample data:

```
Continent   country religion    gender  population
Asia    China   Christian   male    68410000
Asia    China   Unaffiliated    male    700680000
North America   USA Christian   male    243060000
North America   USA Unaffiliated    male    50980000
South America   Brazil  Christian   male    173300000
South America   Brazil  Unaffiliated    male    15410000
Asia    China   Christian   female  24363526.41
Asia    China   Unaffiliated    female  52308051.93
North America   USA Christian   female  12829311.53
North America   USA Unaffiliated    female  17756518.63
South America   Brazil  Christian   female  85172307.14
South America   Brazil  Unaffiliated    female  12802705.11
```

Comment: can you provide a working fiddle/jsbin/plnkr with your code?

Comment: @iulian here is the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/GM71819/bfz6k3m6/.  I dont know how to link my csv to this fiddleso requesting you to see the sample data embedded in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pre-process your data right after you've got it so that d3 will simply take and draw it.

For this, you'll need a function similar to the one below:

```
function combineMaleAndFemale (data) {
    var temp = {};
    var result = [];

    // Add up population from the same continent and country
    data.forEach(function (value) {
        var combinedKey = value.Continent + '_' + value.country;
        if (!temp.hasOwnProperty(combinedKey)) {
        temp[combinedKey] = value;
      } else {
        temp[combinedKey].population += value.population;
      }
    });

    // Generate an array with combined population values.
    for (prop in temp) {
        if (temp.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        result.push(temp[prop]);
      }
    }

    return result;
  }
```

And then, in your `render` function, pre-process the data you receive.

```
function render(data){

    var nested = d3.nest()
      .key(function (d){ return d[layerColumn]; })
      .entries(data);

    // For each religion type, pre-process the data to add up populations.
    nested.forEach(function(religion) {
        religion.values = combineMaleAndFemale(religion.values);
    });
    ...
```

Here is a [working fork](https://jsfiddle.net/3aL47m4y/) of your fiddle.

Comment: many thanks. this looks perfectly fine. Can i add radio button and dropdowns to filter the data further? For example, I wish to have a gender radio button and a continent dropdown. I could have done it easily using jquery but in d3 is there a method which i can use to filter the data?

Comment: You can use the `.on('click')` event handler in `d3`, which is similar to that of `jQuery`, or you can combine both jquery and d3, if it is not a problem for you. Check out [this](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5d621a60e2d1d02086bf) example of handling mouse click events in d3.

Comment: @Glenn, in case you think my answer addressed your original question, do you mind marking it as the accepted answer? So that other people who face the same problem know that this solution works. Best regards!

Comment: sure thing. but how do I do that?

Comment: There's a check sign below the nr of votes counter of the answer. Click on it and it will turn green.

Comment: did it @iulian. could you please tell me how can i filter data based on filters?

Comment: this is subject of another potential question on SO, but I would suggest you try first to achieve this by yourself. In case you don't succeed at least provide/add to your current fiddle the filters you want and then we could see what to do...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110512/discussion-between-glenn-and-iulian).